# How can I get ImageView position with support Right To Left direction

Tags: android, layout, imageview, right-to-left

I want to get the position of my ImageView programmatically. That position is for imageView in pixels relative to screen NOT to parent. actually I found some solutions when searching they working While the Layout Direction is left-to-right, but when I change direction to right-to-left it gives me strange values( is this  isseu).
How can i get the position when the activity is rtl supporting.

some solution I have found:

```
1) private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
    return myView.getTop();
else
    return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());} 


2) image.getLocationOnScreen(int[] locaiton);
```

**UPDATE**

In my activity i have three imageviews , i move (translte animation) image3 from image1 to image2 . start moving from position image1 to position image2, when i use ltr it is animate correctlly but when i change supportrtl="true" i do not see the animation at all.

this is xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootParent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/piece_FLOAT"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/piece1"
        android:translationZ="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/piece_1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/piece1" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/piece_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/piece1" />



</LinearLayout>
```

this is java class

```
public class AnimateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView  imageViewfrom, imageViewto;
    ImageView  imageViewFLOAT;
    LinearLayout L_33;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animate);

        imageViewfrom = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.piece_1);
        imageViewto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.piece_2);


        imageViewFLOAT = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.piece_FLOAT);

        assert imageViewfrom != null;
        assert imageViewto != null;
        imageViewfrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int[] ToLocation = new int[2];
                imageViewto.getLocationOnScreen(ToLocation);

                float xTO =  ToLocation[0];//imageViewto.getX(); //ToLocation[0];
                float yTO = ToLocation[1];//imageViewto.getY();//ToLocation[1];

                int[] FromLocation = new int[2];
                imageViewfrom.getLocationOnScreen(FromLocation);
                float xFROM = FromLocation[0];//imageViewfrom.getX();///FromLocation[0];
                float yFROM = FromLocation[1]; //imageViewfrom.getY();//FromLocation[1];

                Log.e("xFrom =" + xFROM, "xTo =" + xTO );
                Log.e("yFrom =" + yFROM, "yTo =" + yTO );
              //  Log.e("offset =" + topOffset, "xTo =" + 0);
                ValueAnimator animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewFLOAT, "x", xFROM, xTO).setDuration(1500);
                ValueAnimator animatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewFLOAT, "y", yFROM, yTO).setDuration(1500);
                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                animatorSet.playTogether(animatorX, animatorY);
                animatorSet.start();
                //  Animation an = new TranslateAnimation(xFROM, xTO, yFROM , yTO);
               // an.setDuration(1500);

  //              an.setFillAfter(true);// to keep the state after animation is finished
//                imageViewFLOAT.startAnimation(an);// to start animation obviously
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when I use ltr it work very will but add some pixels. when I use rtl the  animation did not seen. why this happen?

thanks for any help .

Comment: yes, `getLocationOnScreen` is what you want

Comment: I use this method but it given me value out of screen border. I do not know why?

Comment: so what do you get?

Comment: when ltr imageView_top = 42, imageView_left = 168, but when rtl imageView_top = 426, imageView_left = 168

Comment: in my activity i have three imageviews , i move (translte animation) image3 from image1 to image2 . start moving from position image1 to position image2, when i use ltr it is animate correctlly but when i change supportrtl="true" i do not see the animation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here isn't really in finding the `View`'s location, as that shouldn't be affected by the layout direction. The real problem is that `View` animations - especially those involving translations - apparently don't work well with RTL layouts. This is not surprising, since `View` animations have been around since the first versions of Android, but RTL support was only added in API level 17.

The solution is to use [Property Animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) instead.

For example, in your snippet, you're actually only translating that `ImageView` along the x-axis, so we can replace your entire `TranslateAnimation` setup with one line:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewFLOAT, "x", xFROM, xTO).setDuration(1500).start();
```

This creates an `ObjectAnimator` that modifies `imageViewFLOAT`'s x-coordinate - by calling its `setX()` method - in the range `[xFROM...xTO]` over a duration of 1500 milliseconds, and immediately starts it.

Using an `AnimatorSet`, we can combine multiple animations to play together, so you can simultaneously perform a y-translation, as well. For example:

```
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
as.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewFLOAT, "x", xFROM, xTO), 
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewFLOAT, "y", yFROM, yTO));
as.setDuration(1500).start();
```

Property animations and their classes are rather straightforward, and can do pretty much anything that the old `View` animations could. Updating your code to use these should be a simple fix for your RTL animation issues.

Comment: but there is some thing image3 moves from image1 to image2 with adding some pixels Why? Suppose it coordinates image1(20,20) and image2(40,20) when I use ObjectAnimator it goes correctly but it add some pixels at y coordinate. image3 animate from (20,56) to (40,56). why it add 36 pixels.

Comment: How are you getting the `FROM` and `TO` values? You want to use `getX()` and `getY()` for both sets. I guess I forgot to mention that in the answer. I didn't think of it, 'cause we'd discussed in our chat.

Comment: My question was to share your information with others. THANKS alot. your answer is accepted.

Comment: Was that the problem? Is it working as expected now?

Comment: Ah, good. Glad I could help. I'll update the answer later on, when I get a chance to write an adequate update. Cheers!

Comment: In android KitKat the animation dose not work. imageViewFloat disappear and the animation dose not seen. Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm, no. I tested it on my KitKat device, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I have tested my application in two Kitkat devices and it has not worked Do you know which api work for?

Comment: Ok I understand you [this link](https://pastebin.com/4RWpB13S) I paste my code.I tested it in KitKat the animation did not seen and tested it in Marshmello it works.

Comment: Oh, it's just your layout. `View` elevation wasn't introduced until API level 21, so the `translationZ` attribute you have on the floating `View` doesn't do anything on KitKat. On that version, and earlier ones, a `View`'s z-location depends only on its position in the list of child `View`s. That is, `View`s listed first in the parent layout are "on the bottom"; i.e., further away from you on the z-axis. It's actually animating, but it's behind the other `View`s, so you can't see it. Move the `piece_FLOAT` `<ImageView>` to the end of the layout, right before the closing `</RelativeLayout>` tag

Comment: It works @Mike M. thank you.  As you mention I was adding this line `android:translationZ` in xml for piece_Float . This attribute in API 21 and KitKat API is 19 so animation did not seen. About z-location I reorder my views. Sorry to bother you and Thank you for your cooperation with me.

Comment: No problem. It took me a minute to figure out what was going on there, myself. It was definitely not immediately obvious. Glad you got it working. Cheers!